# How does the server node restart the client node after receiving the message (Apache Ignite .Net 2.8.1)

Tags: .net, ignite

I started one Ignite Server project and one Ignite Client project in code, and the need now is to restart the corresponding Ignite Client node when the Server receives the Client message.Has anybody done that?I look at the Ignite GitHub source.Net is not **restartNodes** method, but Java is there[java doc link](https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/IgniteCluster.html), how can I do?Currently, the server can get **IClusterNode** information from the client.
This my server listen message code:

```
        public class RestartNodeMessageListener : IMessageListener<string>
        {
            private readonly IIgnite server;
            public RestartNodeMessageListener(IIgnite server)
            {
                this.server = server;
            }
            
            public bool Invoke(Guid nodeId, string message)
            {
                var clientNodeInfo = server.GetCluster().GetNode(nodeId);
                return true;
             }
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

Seems like it's true, that there is no build-in #restartNodes method for the .NET side.

You can vote for the [IGNITE-3881](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-3881) to become implemented more quickly.

Meanwhile, it's possible to adopt the java version.
Basically, the cluster#restartNodes just executes a killing Compute call on a given nodes:

```
ctx.grid().compute(forNodeIds(ids)).execute(IgniteKillTask.class, true);
```

The source code of the [IgniteKillTask](https://github.com/apache/ignite/blob/master/modules/core/src/main/java/org/apache/ignite/internal/cluster/IgniteKillTask.java) is quite straightforward and there should not be many difficulties traversing it into the C# version. The Java API for the `G.restart` and `G.kill` could be replaced by `Ignition.Stop` and `Ignition.Start` methods.

Comment: Thank you very much.Because it's a.net Core project, I can't use the Java API.I'll try it the way you say.

Comment: Maybe there is something wrong with my method. I still haven't solved it.

Comment: You can use C#'s compute API to implement IgniteKillTask in C#,